# I am facing a weird problem when inserting data from an SQL Stored procedure into a table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, table-variable

I have this stored procedure:

**Lemma 1**: exec GetData 1, '20220301', **1**

I run it with **1** as one of the parameters, It does correctly return some data

[image]

**Lemma 2**: exec GetData 1, '20220301', **15**

I run it with other parameter (**15**), it returns the same table and data as before, which is correct.

[image]

Now, for the **VOODOO**:

**Lemma 3:** we understand that the stored procedure is correctly returning the same dataset for the two different parameters, **1** and **15**

So we go one step further, I want to insert the values into a table variable.

The problem is, with parameter **1**, the table variable is being filled correctly. With parameter **15**, although we have the same dataset as result, the table variable is not being filled.

**example:**

```
set nocount on
declare @tmp table (
         Id int primary key identity(1,1)
        ,ShoppingMallId int
        ,EntranceGateId int
        ,CameraId int
        ,[Period] bigint
        ,CountIn int
        ,CountOut int) 
insert into @tmp
exec GetData 1, '20220301', 1
select * from @tmp
```

In the above code, with 1 as parameter, the @tmp table is filled with the correct data.

[image]

In the below code, with parameter 15, no data is filled, although the exec is returning the data.

```
set nocount on
declare @tmp table (
         Id int primary key identity(1,1)
        ,ShoppingMallId int
        ,EntranceGateId int
        ,CameraId int
        ,[Period] bigint
        ,CountIn int
        ,CountOut int) 
insert into @tmp
exec GetData 1, '20220301', 15
select * from @tmp
```

[image]

Any ideas???

Comment: FYI `@tmp` is *not* a temporary table, it is a table variable. Temporary tables and table variables are *very* different and should not be confused.

Comment: As for the question, if there is no data in the table variable `@tmp` after the statement `INSERT INTO @tmp exec GetData 1, '20220301', 15` then the procedure did *not* return any data; it's as simple as that. If you are adamant that this is not the case, then provide a [mre].

Comment: What's on the _Messages_ tab when you `exec GetData 1, '20220301', 15`? I expect to see some rowcount shenanigans.

Comment: The OP has `set nocount on`, @AlwaysLearning , there won't be (though they could obviously set it back to `OFF` and remove the statement).

Comment: @Larnu, the caller has `set nocount on`. Do you know what's inside the stored procedure?

Comment: Even if you explicitly turn `NOCOUNT` to `OFF` within the procedure, the outer scope's setting would be honoured, @AlwaysLearning . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a29a5f504fe94113dc6ce9f4c90946bd)

Comment: I would assume that your stored procedure is doing something different when the parameter is 15. Could it be that parmeter 15 is doing something extra that parameter 1 skips? Perhaps Parameter 15 results in two result sets, one empty and the second one with your data. I assume the problem is inside your stored procedure and you need to share more information about the source of you stored procedure or at least show us the Results tab and the Messages tab if you just exec the stored procedure with both parameters but without the insert into @tmp

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your attempts to help me solve this problem, but the problem lies somewhere else. It was a misconception from my side.

From my point of view, my stored procedure "GetData" returns a dataset, and my misconception was that regardless of how that data was selected, once the data is available we should be able to insert it.

**I was wrong!**

The issue was this: my stored procedure gets the data from 2 different data sources. So for the value 1, I have data from source A, for the value 15, I have data source B. Until here, there is no problem, as both are retrieving same dataset, same parameters, same type.

The problem lies that in stored procedure B (the one used with parameter 15), there is also a temp table that I insert into

**The problem: Nested Inserts.**

Basic rule: *'We cannot insert into a temp table when we select from a stored procedure that also inserts into some temp table (nested inserts)'*

It still is weird to me, because the dataset set is there.. But Bill knows better...

This was the error I found in my logs:
**Error number**: 8164
**Error message**: An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.